# Display items according to date - Timeline style

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**UPDATED**
**ANSWER ACCEPTED**

I have a database in which entries (items) can be categorized by date.

e.g.

[image]
...et cetera

Using PHP I want to display the items according to their respective date and have the date as their heading. All items with the same date should be under the same heading (date).

e.g.
Output:

[image]
...et cetera

I'm not completely new to PHP so I don't mind advanced methods. I have some experience in Javascript too.

I've been able to use `mysql_query` statements to display all the items according to their dates, but **only one date at a time**.

I'd like to display all items at once, but in the form of a timeline as seen above with multiple items under the same heading according to their dates.

Comment: You need to provide some evidence that you've at least _tried_ to work on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below updated code

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM tablename
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$date = $row['Date_Added'];
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM tablename
    WHERE `Date_Added` == '$date'
    SQL;

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    echo "<h1>$date</h1>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $type = $row['Item_name'];
    echo "<li>$type</li>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, but how does one accommodate for multiple date entries? The code above only displays items pertaining to "2013/09/14".

Comment: Thanks man this looks good! Thanks for the error handling too, the effort is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Obtain a list of dates (by `select distinct`)
2. For each date in the list do

   a. get the corresponding items by `select item from items where Date_added = $date`

   b. display the date and the items

Comment: Could you explain what the `foreach` statement should look like? I guess one would need to put the results into an array first?

Comment: If you are not completely new to PHP (your own words) a `foreach` should not be a problem, right? The first `select` returns an `array` and you have to iterate over it using a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of [Vishnu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392904/vishnu-vishwa) code:

Using PHP and MYSQL

```
// first, select all the different dates
////////////////////////////////////////

$query = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT Date_added FROM table_name" );
// now fetch the results from the mysql query (above)
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
    // put the dates into a variable i.e. $date
    $date = $row['Date_added'];
    // now one can format the date to output like: "September 20th '13"
    $date_string = date('F js \'y', strtotime('' .$date. ''));
    // display the formatted date
    echo "<h2>" .$date_string. "</h2>";
```

[More info on date manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
// Second, query the database for all items pertaining to each date (no foreach
// statement required)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $cmd = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Date_added='$date'" );
    // now fetch the results from the mysql query (above)
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($cmd) ){
        // put the items into a variable i.e. $item
        $item = $row['Item_name'];

        // display the results
        // note: one can also create a variable and echo that instead
        echo "<p>" .$item. "</p><br/>";

    }
}

// This code can be used to display anything by any category, not just by date
```

By using CSS one can make the tags look really cool, hope you like the timeline.
Vote up if you want PHP code for a date navigation application to add to this.

Apologies for the deprecated code, will update soon